# Alphanumeric regex that supports UTF characters?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

So - for a registration form (username field) I want to allow alphabet characters, numbers, underscores and dashes. The issue is -> user should be able to use their native alphabets, not just latin. So Cyrillic and other characters should be allowed....  but not chars like: $%^*() etc.

```
<?php                                                                           
   $test = 'dshfjfj_-7685гдежзи $@@@@@';
   echo preg_match('/^[\pL\pN_-]+/u', $test);
?>
```

^ above regex results in true, even though I don't wanna allow `@` -> what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use end of line anchor `$` also to avoid matching unwanted input:

```
preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N}_-]+$/u', $test);
```

Comment: Yes you had our regex almost correct, just this minor but critical miss.